# Subir imagen a Google Drive con Apps Script sin utilizar formulario

Tags: google-apps-script, navegador-web, google-drive, subida-de-archivos

Mi intención es subir una imagen que tengo en mi equipo a Google Drive pero con la condición de que no sea a través de un formulario. Necesitaría que a través de Google Apps Script subiese la imagen automáticamente con el código sin tener que pasar por un formulario como intermediario.

Adjunto la solucion que tengo hasta ahora, la cual funciona, pero me obliga a seleccionar la imagen manualmente mediante un formulario:

form.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
 <base target="_top">
</head>

<body>


 <form>
   <input type="file" name="imageFile"/>
   <input type="button" value="Upload" onclick="google.script.run.upload(this.parentNode)">
 </form>


</body>



</html>
```

codigo.gs:

```js
function doGet() 
{
 return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('form.html');
}

function upload(e)
{


 var destination_id = '1cgzNUb88ZHXSQ7iZ0zYigH1f7KD_7geH' //Id de la 
 carpeta en la que vamos a almacenar la imagen 

 var img = e.imageFile

 var contentType = 'image/png'

 var destination = DriveApp.getFolderById(destination_id)

 var img = img.getAs(contentType)

 destination.createFile(img)

}
```

Basicamente lo que me gustaria es proporcinarle al codigo.gs un Path que apunte a un archivo local de mi ordenador y que se suba directamente sin tener que recurrir a un type="file"

[image: Imagen del editor de Google Apps Script]

Comment: Google Apps Script es una plataforma muy amplia, por favor especifica a que parte de esta plataforma te refieres, muestra lo que has intentado y agrega una breve descripción de lo que buscado/investigado.

Comment: Buenas Ruben, gracias por tu respuesta. Ya he editado la pregunta pero me sigue saliendo cerrada. No tengo claro si debo hacer algo más para reabrirla. Gracias y un saludo!

Comment: Recién me entero de que actualizaste este pregunta porque se compartión el enlace en la sala principal de [chat] hace unos momentos :)

Comment: He revisado la edición de la pregunta y la he editado. Lamentablemente la pregunta sigue ser una pregunta apropiado para este sitio pues carece de detalles suficientes. Google Apps Script es una plataforma, deberías ser más específico en relación a cómo quieres usarlo. Si te vas a limitar a usuarlo desde un navegador, lamento decirte que lo estás buscando hacer no es posible. Cabe destacar que las preguntas "abiertas" solicitando recomendaciones están fuera de tema.

Answer (score 0):

Te comento que hace poco tuve que hacer una asistencia técnica a mi pareja que crea inspecciones y luego después debe crear informes de la misma. Cada inspección tenía que contar con una evidencia fotográfica, lo que decidí hacer para ayudarle fué: que él saque todas las fotos y le coloque el nombre requerido, que será un idImagen, lo tomaré como "Nombre de Archivo" y me ayudará a seguir trabajando con otras hojas. Una vez tenido esto organizado. Subo toda la carpeta con las millones de imágenes (mil y algo en realidad) y ejecuto el siguiente código:

```
function importDataFromDrive() {
  var folderId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; // Cambia "ID_FOLDER" por la ID de la carpeta de Drive que deseas utilizar
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  var files = folder.getFiles();

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetName = folder.getName();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  if (!sheet) {
    sheet = spreadsheet.insertSheet(sheetName);
    sheet.appendRow(["Fecha de Subida", "Nombre del Archivo", "Extensión", "Enlace"]);
  }

  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var fileName = file.getName();
    var fileDate = file.getLastUpdated();
    var fileExtension = fileName.split('.').pop();
    var fileUrl = file.getUrl();
    
    sheet.appendRow([fileDate, fileName, fileExtension, fileUrl]);
  }
}
```

Debes tener presente que una vez tengas esto armado, te ha quedado listado y con id mas enlace para luego seguir trabajando en pasos futuros.

PD.Recuerda que el nombre de las celdas debe ser el siguiente: "Fecha de Subida", "Nombre del Archivo", "Extensión", "Enlace"..